# Unable to Create new project in Titanium Studio on Windows 7

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have installed Titanium Studio in windows 7 (64 bit), but I cant able to create new projects. While creating new project I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karthi\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.7.5\project.py", line 100, in <module>
    main(sys.argv,len(sys.argv))
  File "C:\Users\Karthi\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.7.5\project.py", line 91, in main
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(all_dir,file),os.path.join(resources_dir,file))
  File "C:\Users\Karthi\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1313011725\python\lib\shutil.py", line 85, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\Karthi\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1313011725\python\lib\shutil.py", line 51, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Karthi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\1.7.5\\all\\app.js
```

I cant able to understand why this is happening, Also I tried Uninstall the studio and reinstall again. But same error happening again.

Anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when installing on a Windows 7 VM. Titanium was having trouble with the default workspace directory.

Try changing you default Workspace under Preferences\Startup and Shutdown\Workspaces.

After applying this change and restarting Titanium Studio, I was able to create projects.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have changed my default workspace directory, but even I am getting the same error again. Is there any other solutions

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem/solution as zk. Did you change the directory to the suggested default location? (e.g. My Documents) You can also try running Titanium Studio as Administrator (right click the shortcut on your desktop and Run as Administrator).

If that fails, make sure you have everything configured for the project type you are trying to add.

Comment: Running Titanium Studio as Administrator did the trick for me. (Even do it was installed with admin account and run from it I needed to explicitly run it as admin (right click the launcher icon and then "Run as admin")